# How to fix a panel menu in position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to fix a menu in place on a page so the panel doesn't scroll down with the rest of the page. I can't seem to get this to work, the panel menu just scrolls with the rest of the page leaving the menu at the top. any suggestions? Here is what I have:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="fieldpanel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b">

        <!--CONTENT HERE-->


    </div><!-- /field panel -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the css - it will work in most modern browsers but not in IE7 (unless its in standards mode) or previous IE versions.

```
#fieldpanel
{
  position: fixed;
  top:      0;
}
```

Make sure that you have a `DOCTYPE` specified in the first line of the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The HTML5 `DOCTYPE` above should be sufficient for most browsers.

Comment: Nice! Worked perfectly :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
    position="absolute";
```

to the CSS! :)

Comment: Like this: #fieldpanel { position= "absolute" }? It didn't work if so :(

Comment: Are you in a CSS file (.css)? Also, change the brackets ("{}") to parentheses ("()")

Comment: Yes Im in the css file. I also tried position: with no luck. also,    "()" don't work in css, "{}" does.

Comment: Can you link me to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with some more of your code please?

And sorry, I have't worked with CSS in a while and forgot about brackets :P

Comment: Similar, here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/aYF7fNovVZgANViwvXAo?p=preview    if you notice when you open the panel on the left or right, you can scroll and the menu information is left at the top. Thank you for your help!